# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in websphere 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, websphere-7

I'm running in to a strange problem,

i have a web application developed with **spring 2.5**.

i deploy this application in **websphere 7** application sever.

there are two websphere application servers, **the application works fine in one app server, but in the other it gives a strange error** saying that the web application is making a call to a not existing method.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.dfn.mtr.mix.beans.PortfolioRecord.getPendingSell()J

the actual method call the application making is ,

```
com.dfn.mtr.mix.beans.PortfolioRecord.getPendingSell()
```

i attached part of the log below. i can't find any solution when i googled for the problem, hope you guys can give me some assistance in order to resolve the issue. **please let me know if you want further information regarding the issue.**

```
[1/29/14 17:37:29:457 GMT+03:00] 0000004d LoggingInterc E com.directfn.tradeweb.system.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor afterThrowing Exception in method: calcAssetAllocation Exception is: null In class: class com.directfn.tradeweb.system.service.AccountSummaryService
                             java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.dfn.mtr.mix.beans.PortfolioRecord.getPendingSell()J
at com.directfn.tradeweb.system.service.MIXProtocolHelper.toCustomerHolding(MIXProtocolHelper.java:367)
at com.directfn.tradeweb.system.service.AccountSummaryMIXProtocolHelper.toPortfolioServiceResponse(AccountSummaryMIXProtocolHelper.java:150)
at com.directfn.tradeweb.system.service.AccountSummaryService.getPortfolioInternal(AccountSummaryService.java:200)
at com.directfn.tradeweb.system.service.AccountSummaryService.getPortfolio(AccountSummaryService.java:159)
at com.directfn.tradeweb.system.service.AccountSummaryService.calcAssetAllocation(AccountSummaryService.java:250)
at com.directfn.tradeweb.system.service.AccountSummaryService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$4fb54bb2.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:700)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:635)
at com.directfn.tradeweb.system.service.AccountSummaryService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f497980b.calcAssetAllocation(<generated>)
at com.directfn.tradeweb.plugins.inquiry.AccountSummaryPlugin.handleRequest(AccountSummaryPlugin.java:95)
at com.directfn.tradeweb.system.controllers.MainController.handleRequest(MainController.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy100.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1658)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1598)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
at com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:270)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:935)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:503)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:875)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)
```

---

regards,
Rangana

Answer (score 0):

In most of situation, it means your `jar` version is not the corresponding one.
You need to verify if they are correctly versioned.

I think the reason of this is that when `classloader` load the required class, since the class is exist with no other error, it can be loaded into JVM.
But when you call that method, it would fail because in this version of `jar` there might have no required method.

Please check the method `getPendingSell()` in this class `com.dfn.mtr.mix.beans.PortfolioRecord`

If you could not find it manually, you can do further exploration now!

Comment: com.dfn.mtr.mix.beans.PortfolioRecord.getPendingSell() method exist in the jar file, but i found that web application is built using jdk 1.5 , the jar file containing the above method class is from jdk 1.6 , can this have a effect on the problem.

Comment: @ranganaMIT I think it might be the reason! lower jre is not compatible higher jdk

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i suggest to do is:
Go to directory HOME_OF_YOUR_WAS_PROFILE\installedApps\YOUR_APP_NAME and examine jar files there. Try to examine your libs, they may be on ear level or inside war archive. They must be identical on both servers.

If you use Windows as your OS consider the thing that Websphere 7 sometimes do not clear app directory while uninstall. It is very common situation when you change versions of your libs:

1) For example there was a lib file lib1-3.**2.0**.jar.
2) You changed it to lib1-3.**3.1**.jar in your app.
3) You uninstall your app and install new version.
4) Both files are in your lib path and THIS IS THE PROBLEM such as you have.

Comment: app server is on HP UX server, i looked in to the cells and did not found any left over jar files, to confirm i fully uninstalled the application, clear the logs and other temporary files installed did a fresh installation still issue remain same. :-/